# Crash report for Qt UWP app in Microsoft Store

Tags: qt, uwp, crash-reports

I *think* I'm doing everything correctly to build my Qt app for UWP, complete with symbols. I have published this app for PC via the Microsoft Store.

However when I look at the **Microsoft Partner Center > Windows & Xbox > My App > Analytics > Health** page, I see crashes and hangs but I'm unable to get additional information.

In the final "Failures" panel, it shows "Failure name" as "Unknown". When I download the data, I  only get the following:

```
Failure name    Hits    Percentage  
"[object Object]"   "3" "100%"
```

What do I need to do to ensure I get useful crash reports?